# How can I get a timing execution pace using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I tried to code Java Script statements executed by `setTimeout`. My code adds elements to a canvas. I wanted to obtain a sort of animation where some graphical elements are being added to canvas one by one after a few seconds among them.

I tried:

```
for (series in respuesta) {
    if (series != "x" && series != "y" && series != "raiz") {
        (function(x){
            setTimeout(function(){  plot.highlight(1,[respuesta[x].a,0])
                                    plot.highlight(1,[respuesta[x].b,0])},
                                    2500,c,x);                     
            c++;
         }(series))

    }     
}
```

However all I get are ***all staments executed at once*** after a delay. I really thought that as every `setTimeout` is one step in a loop. I would have *n* delays per each of total *n* iterations.

Is there even any simple way to do this using jQuery or any library?

Comment: Did you try setInterVal()? Maybe a good idea to create a fiddle? Add the last Parameter: time

Comment: I think your syntax for `setTimeout` is wrong.  only 2 parameters are allowed.  `setTimeout(function(){ //Your execution statement }, 2500);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the timeouts in a loop. Why don't you increment 2500ms for each loop iteration  so they are spaced evenly, instead of just delayed by the same amount.

```
var  timeout = 2500; 
for (series in respuesta) {
    if (series != "x" && series != "y" && series != "raiz") {
        (function(x){
            setTimeout(function(){  plot.highlight(1,[respuesta[x].a,0])
                                    plot.highlight(1,[respuesta[x].b,0])},
                                    timeout,c,x);                     
            c++;
            timeout += 2500;
         }(series))

    }     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `setInterval()`. This repeats the same function over and over in certain intervals:

```
 var i = 0;
 var myItems = ["a", "b", "c"]
 var myHandle = setInterval(function() {

     // Add new items here.

     i++;

     if (i >= myItems.length) {
        clearInterval(myHandle);
     }

 }, 1000) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try setInterval() in jQuery

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This doesn't fit for this issue.  This does the same execution for every 5 seconds, whereas OP is changing the execution based on the looping.

Comment: Hello Praveen can  u tell me is this code outputs same result in each execution   `var i=0;
  setInterval(function() {
   alert(i);
   i++;
}, 5000);`

Comment: This is just plain JavaScript, not jQuery.